# How to show previous 6 months up to today's date in primefaces calendar

Tags: java, primefaces, calendar

I need your help in applying the below requirement in the primefaces calendar that I can allow the user to select any date range from the calendar component starting from the previous 6 months from today's date until today's date.

To clear the question, the calendar component should allow the user to select date range starting from Dec-2014 up to today's date 1-May-2015 .

My calendar component code is:

```
<p:calendar id="popup3" value="#{user.date4}" pattern="MMM-yyyy" />
```

Comment: Do you want to select a date or a month or a date range? I'm confused by the pattern

Comment: I want to select a date range and then I want to convert it to "MMM-YYYY"

Comment: You might be looking for a mix between the `mindate` and `maxdate` attributes to restrict the calendar's visible dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was done by doing the following:

```
private Date maxCalendarDate = new Date();
private Date minCalendarDate= new Date();
public Date getMinCalendarDate() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(minCalendarDate);
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6);
    minCalendarDate = cal.getTime();        
    return minCalendarDate;
}
```